# How to do cyclical compositing?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to simulate the effect of long exposure on cameras. Using motion blur is a good strategy for short exposures but when I want an extra large exposure (to do some sort of light painting) the effects are undesirable.

I found [this](https://vimeo.com/70818020) alternative way that looks very promising but my skills on the node composition are zero and, unfortunately, the description is too vague.

> In the compositor. Add a file out node, and write every frame to that
>   file, and add that file back into the noodle with an image node.
>   Voila, feedback loop

[Here another reference](https://blenderartists.org/t/long-exposure-effect/580053)

> The planes are animated, and multiple renders are combined using a
>   feedback loop.

Based on the description, it sounds relatively simple and I get the concept but I don't have a clue on how to implement it.

It would seem to me that you need a script to do this, otherwise it doesn't scale up well.